# Knowledge sharing for small teams

Tags: knowledge-management

I have a situation, I need to improve our sharing knowledge for each project and generic things for a small team of five coders.

Do you recommend some tools like Wiki but dedicated for coders that allow to create and share code samples?

Comment: Nice question, though probably better on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). In my opinion, putting code samples on a wiki implies duplicating code and I guess developers will forget it from time to time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atlassian Confluence is a good KB tool in my personal opinion: https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence

It also has code highlighting: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Code+Block+Macro

Comment: Thanks, I already use Jira and I didn't know about that code highlighting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

[IBM RTC](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/)

- Free up to 10 coders
- Share source code
- Share work items among members with descriptions
- You can apply agile on it